# Cardinality of the inverse image of a point under a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cardinals

Let $f:\mathbb R\to [1,3]$ be a continuous function such that

(i) $f^{-1}(1)$ and $f^{-1}(3)$ are singletons.

(ii) $f^{-1}(x)$ contains exactly two points for all $x\in (1,2)\cup (2,3)$.

How to find the possible cardinality of $f^{-1}(2)$?

Since $f$ is continuous, one can use intermediate value theorem. But after that I could not fix the problem. Any suggestions please!

Comment: @DonThousand I think he means $f^{-1}[\{x\}]$ has two points for all $x\in (1,2)\cup (2,3)$, not that $f^{-1}[(1,2)\cup(2,3)]$ is a two-point set.

Comment: @DonThousand It can also be $2^{\aleph_0}$ (e.g. add an interval of constancy where it hits $2$). The question is whether it can be anything else.

Answer (score 3):

All the possibilities are $1$, $2^{\aleph_0}$. Examples are given by others. It is helpful to draw a picture when you read the following proof.

Firstly we can suppose $f^{-1}(1)<f^{-1}(3)$. Otherwise we can consider $f(-x)$. So we will not lose the possibilities of cardinality of $f^{-1}(2)$ by doing this.

Let $a=f^{-1}(1)$, $b=f^{-1}(3)$. We will do the following steps.

(1) There is at least one element $x\in (a,b)$ such that $f(x)=2$.

(2) $f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$. $f$ is decreasing on $(b,+\infty)$. $f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,a)$.

(3) If there are two distinct elements $x_1,x_2\in(a,b)$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=2$, Then Card$(f^{-1}(2))=2^{\aleph_0}$.

(4) It is not possible that $\exists x\in(-\infty,a)$, such that $f(x)=2$. Similar for $(b,+\infty)$.

(5) Conclude that Card$f^{-1}(2)$ is $1$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Proof of (2): If $f$ is not increasing, we can get $c,d$ satisfying $a<c<d<b$ such that $f(c)>f(d)$. Then by intermediate value theorem, $f$ will hit any value in $(f(d),f(c))\backslash\{2\}$ at least three times. Contradiction! It is similar for the remaining two.

(3) Because $f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$.

(4) If $\exists x\in(-\infty,a)$ such that $f(x)=2$. Let $y=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)$. Then $y\ne 3$ (Otherwise we can not arrang $x$ in $(b,+\infty)$) and $y\notin f^{-1}((-\infty,a))$. So there exists $x_2\in(b,+\infty)$ such that $f(b)=y$. Then we hit $f(b+1)$ at least three times. Contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rgpochb6re) function has $|f^{-1}(2)|=1$, while [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lygsk3xwvg) function has $|f^{-1}(2)|=c$. It's not clear whether any other possibilites exist.